# How could an Earthlike planet have two moons, one similar to the Earth's moon and the other primarily composed of carbon?

Tags: planets, earth-like, moons, orbital-mechanics, solar-system

I am building an Earthlike planet that possesses two moons, one similar to the Earth's in terms of chemical composition and one primarily composed of carbon. How could these two moons form? Which moon is likely to be farther from the planet and which one will likely be closer to the planet? Which one is likely to be larger and which one is likely to be smaller?

Comment: VTC:Needs More Focus. You are allowed to ask one and only one question. There's actually four questions here (the title question and the first question in the body of your post need not, and generally would not, be answered identically).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not so much word building as it is "How do natural satellites form?", which is well suited to Astronomy SE. Also, there is nothing that prevents you from straight up stipulating "this planet has two moons, one large, one small". Making the fictional formation of these moons conform to some kind of probability will not aid your worldbuilding.

Answer (score 7):

## Depends on multiple factors

Carbon doesn't exist in its pure state. It exists as carbon dioxide, methane or other compounds. Carbonates, while still present in space, are ultra-depleted, meaning that you would have to dig deep into space before you find a asteroid or a similar body containing a significant amount of carbonates. The reason for this is currently unknown, but I think it has something to do with oxygen getting bound to more reactive stuff like hydrogen or silicon.

If you want a planet that has carbon/carbon chemicals on its surface only, then the answer is just a doorstep away:[image]

Titan, a moon of Saturn may be a bit close to what your question may be demanding, It has lakes of liquid methane (literally liquid natural gas, for laymen), and an atmosphere that contains about 6% methane.

However, if you want a pure carbon moon, then the answer becomes a bit tricky.

Your protoplanetary disk would have to be enriched in carbon and poor in oxygen. Meaning that stuff like silicates, oxides, hydrates etc. would be severely depleted in the protoplanetary disk.

I yet haven't found out how can a protoplanetary disk can be depleted of oxygen, since there are limited papers on the internet. But I guess it has something to do with frost-line or a similar thing.

### Most plausible scenario: Captured Carbon Moon

Your planet and moon form normally (i.e. Theia beats the sh*t out of baby Earth and creates the moon). You have a normal oxygen-rich Earth and Moon, meaning that the Earth and Moon are comprised of silicates and other oxygen bearing compounds, rather than a carbon-dominated planet.

Your other moon, however, is forming somewhere else, far away from Earth's orbit, where temperatures are cool enough to allow carbon-bearing chemicals to exist in a solid state, so that carbon-bearing compounds like methane and ethane accumulate into a disk. This would also attract some elemental carbon into the mix, which would most likely settle out as graphite, and if your moon is large enough, perhaps a layer of diamond.

Your carbon to-be moon then strays into the orbit of Earth. Instead of colliding and recreating Theia 2.0, your CM somehow enters into a stable orbit around the Earth. Your CM is now stably orbiting the Earth along with Normal Moon. The gravity from CM should perhaps cause some perturbations in NM's orbit, which means you would have lesser/more tides, depending on what happens next, but mostly, life on Earth is unhindered.